# Given two samples that have the same mean, standard deviation, and N: are the values in each sample identical?

Tags: distributions, mean, standard-deviation, sample-size

If not, are there any restrictions that would need to be imposed to ensure that the values of the two samples would be identical? I apologize in advance if this is such a basic question.

Comment: Obligatory link to the datasaurus: https://www.autodeskresearch.com/publications/samestats

Comment: Abstract mathematics is extremely helpful with this kind of question, because it suggests that two statistics impose just two conditions on the $N$ numbers, leaving (generically) a solution space of $N-2$ dimensions.  Thus, we would intuitively expect the answer to be *no* whenever $N$ exceeds $2,$ except for very special values of those statistics (such as an SD of $0$).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Given two samples that have the same mean, standard deviation, and N: are the values in each sample identical?

In general, not unless N=2 in both samples. If N is larger than 2, they can differ.

You can see this simply by trying it with some simple cases.

Perhaps the easiest case is to take an asymmetric sample of size $N=3$ and flip it around its mean ($2,3$ and $7$ have a mean of $4$; if you take a new sample of $6,5$ and $1$, respectively, it has the same mean and the same magnitude of deviations from the mean as the original sample, so it will have the same variance and hence standard deviation).

For another example consider these three samples of size three that have the same standard deviation:

Set A: $-1, 0, 1$

Set B: $-a, -a, 2a\quad$  (where $a = \sqrt{\frac13}$)
(i.e. approximately -.57735,-.57735,1.1547)

Set C: $-2b, -b, 3b\quad$   (where $b = \sqrt{\frac17}$)
(i.e. approximately -0.7559289, -0.3779645,  1.1338934)

These all have mean 0 and sd 1. You can make any other mean and sd from these by multiplying by the desired standard deviation and then adding the desired mean.

> If not, are there any restrictions that would need to be imposed to ensure that the values of the two samples would be identical?

Sure, you need additional restrictions that reduce the available degrees of freedom for the data down to 0. These restrictions might take many forms, e.g. specifying skewness, or the median or the sample maximum, etc.

Not all additional restrictions will always work to reduce the free dimensions by one (with some sets of existing restrictions, some additional restrictions may be redundant), but that's usually what it takes.

Comment: "you need additional restrictions that reduce the available degrees of freedom for the data down to 0" - there are exceptions, but in general I believe the number of parameters to identify a singular dataset would tend towards N. This seems related to [the pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), in that you can't generally represent more data with less data without losing some information.

Comment: One possibly notable exception here is a standard deviation of 0, which would mean all elements are just equal to the mean. If the mean and N are then also equal, you'd know two samples are identical.

Answer (score 15):

[image: All of these data sets have the same mean, SD and n]

No. Many data sets can yield the same mean, SD and n.

In the graph above, the three data sets on the left of each graph all share the same mean, SD and n. So do the three data sets on the right of each graph. This is Figure 1 from: Weissgerber, T.L., Milic, N.M., Winham, S.J., and Garovic, V.D. (2015). [Beyond bar and line graphs: time for a new data presentation paradigm](http://dx.plos.org/10.1371/journal.pbio.1002128). PLoS Biol 13: e1002128.

Comment: As far as visualisations are concerned, there's also [Anscombe's quartet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anscombe%27s_quartet) that comprises 4 datasets with very similar (and even exactly equal in some cases) summary statistics but very different distributions; and also the [datasaurus dozen](https://www.autodeskresearch.com/publications/samestats).

Comment: This answer could be improved by providing some explanation for how and why this happens. Relying on an image makes the answer less accessible and others may not be seeing the same things in the image as you are.